# Streaming Desktop using FFMPEG in Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, streaming

How to stream Desktop using FFMPEG in Windows?

I have tried
`ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

and after that this to stream

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i video="Chicony USB 2.0 Camera"  -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts        udp://192.168.2.7:6666?pkt_size=188?buffer_size=65535
```

Using this i got to stream the Camera.

What command do I have to type to stream the Desktop in Windows?

Answer (score 7):

Capture desktop using [built-in GDI screengrabber](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Usebuilt-inGDIscreengrabber):

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv
```

Stream it:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://192.168.2.7:6666
```

Play the stream:

```
ffplay -f mpegts udp://192.168.2.1:6666
```

Save the stream:

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://192.168.2.1:6666 output.mkv
```

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/1153188/285720) you can find an example with audio in the same stream.

And don't worry if the video stream doesn't start immediately and ffmpeg ouputs errors like "[non-existing PPS 0 referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005436/errors-when-decode-h-264-frames-using-ffmpeg)" - you just didn't receive a keyframe yet, wait a dozen of seconds and it should come up.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use `UScreenCapture`. It's using the DShow API of DirectX, and available for both x86 and x64 architectures. After you installed it, you'll find a new input source "UScreenCapture", witch is your live desktop screen respectively.

If you're sending it to a Wowza server, here's the command what you need:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -s **width** x **height** -r **framerate** -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v **bitrate** -an -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://**your.destination.url:PORTNUMBER**?pkt_size=1316
```

Note that I explicitly changed the pixel format(pix_fmt), because ffmpeg used `yuv444p` instead of `yuv420p`. I had to do this to make it work.

It works pretty well for me.

Regards, G.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds). Either 64-bit or 32-bit
   should work.
2. Install [Screen Capturer Recorder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/screencapturer). The installer should automatically
   install *Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable* as well, if
   needed.
3. Use

   ```
   ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -r 24000/1001 -q 1 out.avi
   ```

[FFmpeg screencast Windows](http://svnpenn.github.io/2012/07/ffmpeg-screencast-windows)

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do it without 3rd party applications??

Comment: On Win systems the answer is unfortunately no.

Comment: If you have Linux system (with running X server), you can use the built in **x11grab** device like this:

`ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i :0.0 [...]`


Check the official documentation [here].(http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#toc-x11grab)