# Network Stream video+audio FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

**My Problem**

I'm trying to stream my desktop screen with the audio **from the default device** to my other computer in the local network. The desktop stream is working well using Gdigrab,
but the audio is not working. I've tried some things and I've looked through the FFmpeg documentation. Excuse me if I'm getting something wrong here, but I'm currently learning FFmpeg.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab  -framerate 90 -video_size 1920x1080
-i desktop -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset 
ultrafast -f mpegts udp://ip 
-acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 -re -f udp://ip
```

Is it possible to stream audio and video like this with FFmpeg?

Comment: Don't [crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40954034/5726027).  Like I said there, there's no audio input specified. Run `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` to get a list of audio inputs.

Comment: I crossposted because i was downvoted i worried that Stackoverflow isnt the right Site.

Comment: It isn't, but you can flag it for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to **solve** my problem using the following command.

```
$ ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop \
    -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -vcodec libx264 \
   -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv422p -f mpegts udp://ip
```

Works excellent!

Answer (score -1):

Major bug in your code if there is no sound or a quite phase no recording . This code depends on audio and if not present no record. Easy to miss . This goes back to ffmpeg having major problems that no one wants to fix