# Using FFMPEG to stream desktop, screen, and applications over http

Tags: ffmpeg, browser, streaming, http

As described in this [post](https://superuser.com/a/1556306/1320270) for Windows, I already know how to stream desktop to a player like ffplay or vlc. To access the stream in any browser, I would like to be able to stream my desktop or a single window through HTTP (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Brave, Opera, etc). The goal for such capability is to be able to pick up a fresh system that doesn't have ffplay, vlc, or internet to access the application to stream but will have a browser handy to view the streamed content. I have come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017930/how-to-stream-with-ffmpeg-via-http-protocol), and have attempted with such `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -re -i desktop -listen 1 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov http://localhost:8080
```

Ultimately, sadly, no luck.
[image]
I am working on Windows 10 at the moment, but an OS agnostic approach for Linux and perhaps MacOS in the future would be ideal.

##### Update 4/6/2023:

Found a method to stream main desktop, but it is very laggy on windows 10.

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -f gdigrab -re -i desktop -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -listen 1 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -pix_fmt yuv420p http://localhost:8080
```

Tested on Chrome, but the stream would never open but only download a ~4MB `download` file. Firefox seemed to render it, but it is laggy/slow. Brave browser would either also attempt to download a `download` file or give an error `Error writing trailer of http://localhost:8080: Error number -10053 occurred`. Below are the version of ffmpeg and browsers used.

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
```

Chrome:

```
Version 111.0.5563.147 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Firefox version:

```
111.0.1 (64-bit)
```

Brave:

```
Version 1.50.114 Chromium: 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Still exploring options.